# Edit Custom Views programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-custom-view

I created a layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rlMenu"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/dark_rectangle_bord"
        android:id="@+id/rl1dia"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/sizeCard"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sizeCard"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_bottom_cards"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_end_cards"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_end_cards"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_start_cards"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_start_cards"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_top_cards">

        <TextView
            android:text="1º Dia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv1dia"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textColor="@color/Branco"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/texto_pequeno"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <ImageView
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_calendario_1"
            android:id="@+id/iv1dia"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/sizeImage"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/sizeImage"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />
```

After that, I had included it on my MainActivity.

```
    <include
    android:id="@+id/my_custom_view"
    layout="@layout/custom_view></include>
```

But in this Custom View there are a `RelativeLayout`, a `ImageView` and a `TextView`. I need to create some Custom Views dynamically, sample as below.

**How can i create this Custom View Programatically?**
Ex.:

```
   Button bt = new Button(MainActivity.this);
```

**And how can I change the `TextView`, `RelativeLayout`, background and the `ImageView` programatically?** Like:

```
  CustomView cv = new CustomView(MainActivity.this);
  cv.setImage(R.drawable.chips);
  cv.setRlBackground(Color.WHITE);
  cv.setText("Hello, World!");
```

Comment: you should make the layout in the mainactivity directly and not make it somewhere else and then include it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LayoutInflater  for that

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View mView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
    View email = (View) mView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    yourParentView.addView(mView);
```

But make sure when you add view to its parent call `removeAllview()` method of yourParentView

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to create an actual custom `View`, using include will not create a custom `View` but will only inject in your layout that particular xml. So, create a class (in this case extends `RelativeLayout` but you can use whatever suits you here)

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout {

    private TextView textView;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        inflate(context, R.layout.custom_view, this);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    }

    public void setImage(int resId){
        imageView.setImageResource(resId);
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        textView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

an xml of the layout of your custom View (`custom_view.xml`), you might want to use `merge` instead of `include` since you already have a parent layout (`RelativeLayout` in this case)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        />
</merge>
```

add your custom view to the `Activity` layout like this, please note that you need to use the full name of the custom `View` class you're using, in this case `com.example.lelloman.dummy.CustomView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <com.example.lelloman.dummy.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/custom_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in your `Activity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    CustomView customView = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.custom_view);
    customView.setImage(R.drawable.some_icon);
    customView.setText("Hello world");
}
```